# Файлы облачной версии Битрикс24. REST API для облачного Битрикс24

Tags: php, веб-программирование, битрикс, битрикс24

Смотрел видео [«Встраиваемся» в интерфейс. Кастомизируй Битрикс24 правильно!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=odx3zdi1BrQ&t=36s) с 9:45 по 14:30. Там на 13:02 открывается в редакторе, как я понял папка с bitrix24

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

У меня стоит облачная Битрикс24.

1. Как мне открыть эту папку (как её найти)?
2. Как найти папку для коробочной версии Битрикс24?
3. Помогите найти хорошие материалы по встраиванию/кастомизации в Битрикс24 (не такие как [«Встраиваемся» в интерфейс. Кастомизируй Битрикс24 правильно!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=odx3zdi1BrQ&t=36s)).
4. На [Пишем простейшее приложение для Битрикс24 испльзуя REST API](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4-AHCMKmvZo&t=87s) показано как произвести изменение интерфейса с помощью REST API (т.е. происходит встройка в интерфейс). Но c 5:00 по 5:30 происходит создание файла (настройки приложения приведены на 2:00-5:00)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как видно из скриншота создан файл приложения Битрикс24 на диске **С:** (`C:\users\sympler\appdata\local\temp\sublime-sftp-browse-1561714872\b24.unibix.ru\my_dublicates.php`), т. е. правильно ли я понимаю, что это коробочная версия, а не облачная, поскольку используется локальный диск (в облаке используется сервер). Т.е. с помощью REST API можно встраиваться в интерфейс Битрикс24 только в коробке, а не в облаке?

P.S. Я действовал как на [Пишем простейшее приложение для Битрикс24 испльзуя REST API](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4-AHCMKmvZo&t=87s) с 2:00 по 5:00 и получил

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Это потому что у меня облачный, а не коробочный Битрикс24?

P.S.2. Правильно ли я понял, что для **облачного** Битрикс24 нельзя получить доступ к исходникам, чтобы с помощью **REST API** (**именно с помощью REST API**) встроиться в интерфейс Битрикс24 (в отличие от **коробки**)?

Comment: Облачная версия на то и облачная, чтобы никто не лез туда и не правил всякое. Тебе видимо надо изучить [этот курс](https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/learning/course/index.php?COURSE_ID=99&INDEX=Y)

Comment: @u_mulder правильно ли я понял. что встроиться в облачный Битрикс24 невозможно?

Comment: Нет, он же где-то в облаке и доступов к нему у тебя нет. Иначе все у кого был бы доступ начали корежить его под себя.

Comment: @u_mulder (извините за глупое уточнение, но я новичок в Битрикс24) в том числе невозможно встроиться с помощью REST API?

Comment: Рест-апи и создано для того чтобы как-то взаимодействовать с битриксом.

Comment: @u_mulder, просто на https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4-AHCMKmvZo&t=87s показывается изменение интерфейса с помощью REST API (т. е. происходит встройка в интерфейс Битрикс24), поэтому я и задал вышестоящий вопрос. **Или это видео для коробочной версии Битрикс24?**

Comment: @u_mulder Т. е. с помощью REST API можно встроиться в интерфейс Битрикс24 только в коробке, но не в облаке (судя по тому, что в примере создается **локальный** файл)?

Comment: @u_mulder извините за беспокойство (извините за настырность), я новичок в Битрикс24, я хочу утонить насчет REST API в облаке. прокомментируйте 4-й пункт вопроса, пожалуйста.